# JTextField can't be focused with mouse on Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, swing, jpanel

We are tasked with making a simple game. Now, we have had the game done for a long while now, but I have only just gotten around to implementing the join/host menu (using a JPanel in our JFrame, which only contains a canvas which is used to render our sprites/shapes/etc.). We have 4 JTextFields and two JButtons. Our canvas is set to disabled when this display is shown so as to not interfere with input (i.e., with its mouse listener and such). On Windows machines, we can click on all of the boxes, we get the nice I-beam cursor, etc., and we can type in there normally and then click the buttons. However, when the same is attempted on MacOS, you cannot click on the boxes or the buttons. You don't get the I-beam on the boxes. It's like they don't exist. However, we can use the tab key to switch focus through all elements, and can use that to type in the boxes, press the buttons, etc., just as you should be able to with the mouse. I've tried requesting focus like 20 different ways, but that didn't seem to work. I've made many other apps the same way (JFrame > JPanel > JButton/TextField), and they all have worked just fine on MacOS. I have never seen anything like this before.

Rather than post a whole bunch of entire files, I'll trim them down. The first one is our main entry point, the Game class. It looks something like this:

```
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable
    private JFrame frame;
    private ConnectScreen connectScreen;
    public getFrame() { /* get reference to frame */ }
    public setFrame() { /* set the frame */ }
    public void run() { /* game loop, calls render() */ }
    public Game() { /* create window, add canvas to it, get reference to frame, instantiate stuff, etc. */ }
    public void tick() { /* every frame this happens, just tells spawners to spawn stuff, etc. */ }
    public void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        ///////// Draw things below this/////////////

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        // SCREEN
        if (!isPaused()) {
            // THIS is where we tell the canvas to enable if we're not on the connect screen
            if (gameState != STATE.Join && gameState != STATE.Host) {
                this.setEnabled(true);
            }

            /* i omitted rendering from all of these, since it's not useful here. most say somethingScreen.render(g) or something like that. */
            if (gameState == STATE.Wave || gameState == STATE.Multiplayer || gameState == STATE.Bosses || gameState == STATE.Survival) { // render gameplay items
            } else if (gameState == STATE.Menu || gameState == STATE.Help || gameState == STATE.Credits) { // render menu
            } else if (gameState == STATE.Upgrade) { // render upgrade screen
            } else if (gameState == STATE.GameOver) { // render game over screen
            } else if (gameState == STATE.Leaderboard) { // render leaderboard
            } else if (gameState == STATE.Color) { // render color picker screen
            } else if (gameState == STATE.Join || gameState == STATE.Host) {
                // if we are on the connect screen, disable this canvas
                this.setEnabled(false);
                connectScreen.render(g);
            } else if (gameState == STATE.LeaderboardDisplay) { // render the leaderboard
            }
        } else {
            pauseMenu.render(g);
        }
        if(!isPaused()) {} // renders the handler's things
        ///////// Draw things above this//////////////
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }
}
```

Other than that, there's not much of interest in that class. Here's the (trimmed down) ConnectScreen class:

```
public class ConnectScreen extends JPanel {
    JFrame frame; // this is the frame from the Game class
    JTextField _____; // there are 4 of these
    JButton _____; // there are 2 of these
    public ConnectScreen(Game game) { // the game is passed in to get the frame from it
        super();
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT));
        this.setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT));
        this.game = game;
        this.mpSpawn = mp;
        game.getFrame().add(this);
        this.setFocusable(true);

        /* set up each component */
        /* add each component (click handlers, etc.) */
        /* add panel to frame */
    }
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.paintComponents(g);
    }
}
```

We know the setup of elements and such all worked, since we can see and use them all on Windows, but for some reason when we try it on MacOS, it doesn't work. We can tab-select them and type/press buttons, but for some reason you cannot click on them to focus. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The problem isn't with the text field or the OS, but with the `BufferStrategy`.  Swing components have their own painting mechanism which is not compatible with `BufferStrategy` - as a general rule - you should NEVER call ANY `paint` method directly.

Comment: Instead, you will need to switch between the `JPanel` and the `Canvas` - don't mix Swing components and `BufferStrategy` rendering

Comment: FYI: There is a whole pipeline of functionality which you have stepped over in your attempt to "manually" render the Swing components, this functionality setups the event dispatching process by which the components are notified when events occur. Your attempt is (sorry) naive at best and demonstrates a general lack of knowledge about how the overall API works (no offence, most days, you wouldn't need to know), which is why I'm suggesting not using the `BufferStrategy` this way, but to physically switch between them (add/remove/setVisible what ever)

Comment: *"But it works on Windows"* - but it doesn't work reliably on all platforms/systems - I can't say why it works on Windows, don't have a Windows box to test on, it kind of surprises me, but Windows does seem to always do things differently

Comment: @MadProgrammer The issue here is that I hate Java (I use C++ for everything unless I have to use Java) and I am not the one who originally wrote that code. This particular codebase was made by someone else before us, and we are tasked with making it better. You should see some of the other things he did in this code that make our lives harder. Thanks for the tip though, I'll answer my own question assuming it works.

Comment: On top of that, I had never seen a BufferStrategy before this because I never needed one, so I just assumed it worked the same as if I had used a Graphics2D or something.

Comment: Swing uses a "passive rendering" system, which is controlled by the `RepaintManager` (and Event Dispatching Thread). `BufferStrategy` takes you out of that API and provides you with direct access to the painting system. And yes, I've now inherited two projects which should be scrapped and started again, but because of "money", they won't be and will end up costing more time (and money) to maintain and update

Comment: I might also suggest having a look at [Passive vs. Active Rendering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/rendering.html), [Performing custom painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Panting in Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to get a better idea of how these processes actually work

Comment: Nah, I fixed it. Gonna answer the question in a moment. Thanks for the help. I understand why this doesn't work, it just would never have occurred to me because I just assumed that a BufferStrategy would simply render the Swing components the same way as it buffers other things. Assuming makes a...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, thanks to MadProgrammer. Apparently, a BufferStrategy cannot be used to render Swing components. I just added an `if` statement in `Game::render()` where it only does any rendering if the ConnectScreen isn't shown. If it is, it just disables and turns the canvas invisible, while the `ConnectScreen::render()` (renamed to override `JPanel::paintComponent()`) just uses `super.paintComponent()` to passively draw Swing components.